# “Try vs Install elementary” with live USB

Tags: live-installation

Quick question. I burnt the eOS into my usb flash drive and upon booting from it, I had the option of trying or installing eOS. I went for “try” because i thought installing would erase my entire ssd and replace Windows OS with elementary.

I then switched back to windows and after some time booted eOS once again. Upon doing that, I was again sent to “try or install elementary”, I chose again chose 'try', and all of the changes I have previously made (e.g. downloaded a different browser) were discarded.

What do I do? What will the “Install elementary” option do? Do I have to dual boot in order to save the changes?

Thank you.

Comment: With some work, you could probably make an Elementary live USB with "persistence". Google will happily tell you how. You can install eOS by itself or in a multi-boot configuration. You could even overwrite your existing Windows installation with eOS if you want. The installer has multiple options. But, if you're looking for a live USB that keeps settings, there's unetbootin which will help you configure it with persistence.

Answer (score 0):

most live distros only last one session. there are some images called persistent lives that allow saving your changes, but they are growingly uncommon. try option is meant to try the system before committing to install so you don't have to write your disk. if you plan on using the system on a daily basis then is time to install it. A dual boot setup us quite common and very easy to make. just make sure to pay attention to every step so you don't lose any data during install.